# How do I see DynamoDB Auto Scaling parts of AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, autoscaling

My role has the predefined policy *AutoScalingConsoleReadOnlyAccess*, but when I try to view the auto scaling settings for a DynamoDB table, I get the error "You don't have the required permissions for Auto Scaling." The [linked documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.Console.html#AutoScaling.Permissions) from the error suggests that I need access to these actions:

```
"iam:AttachRolePolicy",
"iam:CreatePolicy",
"iam:CreateRole"
```

This makes no sense to me as these roles have nothing to do with Dynamo or Auto Scaling. What permission or policy does my role require in order to view auto scaling settings in the AWS Console?

Comment: haha, yup, that definitely seems like a Copy/Paste error. I'll look up some permissions for you tonight, unless someone else answers it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, DynamoDB Autoscaling actually uses [Application AutoScaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ApplicationAutoScaling/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

If you want the Users/Roles to have access to **Read** and **Write** the DynamoDB tables, you can simply use **`AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`**, but this will give full access to all tables.

If on the other hand you want to give access to just the scaling properties, I'll give two policies, based on just the AutoScaling Properties.

**View/Modify AutoScaling**:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
      "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
      "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
      "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
      "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
      "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
      "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }]
}
```

**View AutoScaling**:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "application-autoscaling:Describe*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }]
}
```